# Catching UnboundLocalError exceptions

Tags: python, exception

I need to use 'try and except' to catch an error in this code:

```
while hand_numbers > 0:
    hand_type = input('Enter \'n\'to deal a new hand,  \'r\' to replay the last hand, or \'e\' to end game: ')
```

when i type 'r' i get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/mit/mit_w4_pset/ps4a - Copy.py", line 310, in <module>
    playGame(wordList)
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/mit/mit_w4_pset/ps4a - Copy.py", line 295, in playGame
    playHand(hand, wordList, HAND_SIZE)

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'hand' referenced before assignment
```

I neeed to replace this error with the phrase:
'You have not played a hand yet. Please play a new hand first!'

I tried the following:

```
while hand_numbers > 0:
    try:
        hand_type = input('Enter \'n\'to deal a new hand,  \'r\' to replay the last hand, or \'e\' to end game: ')
    except UnboundLocalError as Error:
        print('You have not played a hand yet. Please play a new hand first!')
        continue
```

but it is not working.. i have tried also except ValueError and NameError.. nothing works.. any advise please? thanks in advance.

see other code:

```
def playHand(hand, wordList, n):
    """
    Allows the user to play the given hand, as follows:

    * The hand is displayed.
    * The user may input a word or a single period (the string ".") 
      to indicate they're done playing
    * Invalid words are rejected, and a message is displayed asking
      the user to choose another word until they enter a valid word or "."
    * When a valid word is entered, it uses up letters from the hand.
    * After every valid word: the score for that word is displayed,
      the remaining letters in the hand are displayed, and the user
      is asked to input another word.
    * The sum of the word scores is displayed when the hand finishes.
    * The hand finishes when there are no more unused letters or the user
      inputs a "."

      hand: dictionary (string -> int)
      wordList: list of lowercase strings
      n: integer (HAND_SIZE; i.e., hand size required for additional points)

    """
    # BEGIN PSEUDOCODE <-- Remove this comment when you code this function; do your coding within the pseudocode (leaving those comments in-place!)
    # Keep track of the total score
    total_score = 0
    # As long as there are still letters left in the hand:
    while (calculateHandlen(hand)) > 0:
        #Display the hand
        print('Current hand: ', end='')
        displayHand(hand)
        # Ask user for input
        word = input('Enter a valid word, or a "." to indicate that you are finished: ')
        # If the input is a single period:
        if word == '.':
            # End the game (break out of the loop)
            print('Goodbye!')
            break

        # Otherwise (the input is not a single period):
        else:
            # If the word is not valid:
            if isValidWord(word, hand, wordList) == False:
                # Reject invalid word (print a message followed by a blank line)
                print('Invalid word, please try again: \n')
            # Otherwise (the word is valid):
            else:
                # Tell the user how many points the word earned, and the updated total score, in one line followed by a blank line
                score = getWordScore(word, HAND_SIZE)
                total_score = total_score + score
                print('Score earned: ', getWordScore(word, HAND_SIZE), 'Your current total score is: ', total_score, '\n')
                # Update the hand
                hand = updateHand(hand, word)
                if calculateHandlen(hand) == 0:
                    print('You have no more letters to play,Game over!')

    # Game is over (user entered a '.' or ran out of letters), so tell user the total score
    print('Total score for this hand is: '+str(total_score)+' points.')

def playGame(wordList):
    """
    Allow the user to play an arbitrary number of hands.

    1) Asks the user to input 'n' or 'r' or 'e'.
      * If the user inputs 'n', let the user play a new (random) hand.
      * If the user inputs 'r', let the user play the last hand again.
      * If the user inputs 'e', exit the game.
      * If the user inputs anything else, tell them their input was invalid.

    2) When done playing the hand, repeat from step 1    
    """
    # TO DO ... <-- Remove this comment when you code this function
    hand_numbers = 10
    while hand_numbers > 0:
        hand_type = input('Enter \'n\'to deal a new hand,  \'r\' to replay the last hand, or \'e\' to end game: ')
        choices = ['e','n','r']
        if hand_type not in choices:
            print('Invalid command.')
        elif hand_type == 'e':
            print ('Goodbye!')
            break
        else:
            if hand_type == 'n':
                hand = dealHand(HAND_SIZE)
                playHand(hand, wordList, HAND_SIZE)
            elif hand_type == 'r':
                playHand(hand, wordList, HAND_SIZE)
            hand_numbers -= 1
            #print(hand_numbers)

#
# Build data structures used for entire session and play game
#
if __name__ == '__main__':
    wordList = loadWords()
    playGame(wordList)
```

Comment: You have not included the section of code that is erroring. The error is in your call to `playHand()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while hand_numbers > 0:
    hand_type = input('Enter \'n\'to deal a new hand,  \'r\' to replay the last hand, or \'e\' to end game: ')
```

These are not the lines you're looking for. Try-except here will not catch your error.

It is here:

```
if hand_type == 'n':
    hand = dealHand(HAND_SIZE)
    playHand(hand, wordList, HAND_SIZE)
elif hand_type == 'r':
    playHand(hand, wordList, HAND_SIZE)
```

The problem is simple: `hand` is undefined in the second branch (nested under the `elif`). It is only defined in the *first* branch (nested under the `if`). Hence, when you type `r`, an error occurs.

The solution is equally simple: make sure `hand` is defined for both if and elif branches. To do this, you can either move the declaration of `hand` above the if-statement or copy it into the elif branch.

Comment: thanks, I thought about this solution, but the scope to be able to catch the error with the try and except statements.. 
 so this mean that the except statement cannot work with these types of errors? thanks again

Comment: What is the task regarding catching errors with try/except? The problem outlined above does cause an error, but it is such a trivial one that try/except isn't needed. It can be easily fixed on the programming side by moving a line around. It would help if you revealed more of the question (what exactly are you trying to do), otherwise we might be running around in an [xyproblem](http://xyproblem.info/).